# Android Studio - Application has stopped, but 0 code errors

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, runtime-error

My android application was running smoothly before i install some Android Studio updates, and asked me to upgrade gradle etc after the update been installed.

Later on, the Android Studio asked me to update my Android Emulator (Emulator Nexus 5X API 24 Android v7.0), since i've made all these changes, my application has been unable to open when i click run. But remember it has no codding errors when i debug etc.

The error message from Android Monitor is:

```
08-13 14:07:30.735 3889-3889/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.smartlegal.law.freeman.smartlegal, PID: 3889
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.smartlegal.law.freeman.smartlegal/com.smartlegal.law.freeman.smartlegal.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.smartlegal.law.freeman.smartlegal.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
08-13 14:07:30.744 3889-3896/? W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.874ms
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This would include the source code to `onCreate()` of `com.smartlegal.law.freeman.smartlegal.MainActivity`, along with any layout resource(s) loaded by that method.

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

As the error states, you're trying to set an `onClickListener` on a Button that does not exist (returns null). To simplify, when you're defining your Button, you call `findViewById` to associate the Button in Java with an XML element, but the ID that you are passing is not valid - either you're trying to call the `setOnClickListener` before you call `setContentView`, or the ID you are passing to `findViewById` has a typo or simply does not exist in the XML layout file.

Some more information, such as the code to your MainActivity and the layout file, would be useful to determine the exact cause of your problem.

Comment: Yes you're right, i forgot to specify the ID for the editText and Button, that is why it wasnt possible to find them ID on XML. So i've set it up and reloaded the project and it is running smoothly now. Thanks for the support..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're right, i forgot to specify the ID for the editText and Button, that is why it wasnt possible to find them ID on XML. So i've set it up and reloaded the project and it is running smoothly now. Thanks guys for the support.

"As the error states, you're trying to set an onClickListener on a Button that does not exist (returns null). To simplify, when you're defining your Button, you call findViewById to associate the Button in Java with an XML element, but the ID that you are passing is not valid. by: Timothy Langer".